# NodeJs Redis (cache) error handling - how to ignore errors?

Tags: node.js, redis

Currently I have a cache.js file to initiate Redis, in order to reuse the connection.

cache.js

```
 const redis = require('redis');
const { promisify } = require("util");


const client = redis.createClient({ host: process.env.REDIS_HOST, port: process.env.REDIS_PORT, password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD })

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error encountered', err.toString())
    return null
});


const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);
const setexAsync = promisify(client.setex).bind(client);
module.exports = { getAsync, setAsync, setexAsync }
```

how I use it.

```
try {
    const redis = require('lib/cache')
    const results = await redis.getAsync(key)
    if (results) {
        return res.json(JSON.parse(results));
    }

} catch(err) {
    console.log('redis error => ', err) //this is not important, I want to proceed to get data from db.
}
....... continue codes to get data from database since there's no cache.
```

This all works well, until errors ( e.g Redis server down, connection to Redis not available, password wrong etc ), and the node application just stuck.

It doesn't continue, after it console.log the error return by the .on('error') emitted event.

**What I want.**
Because I use it as a cache, I want it to continue to serve and return data from the database, and ignore the cache. The availability of the redis cache is not critical in my application.

How may I achieve what I want?

I tried returning null in the emit event but not working, I also tried to throw error from the .on('error') event but no error is thrown.

Comment: What happens if when it is "stuck" you bring Redis back up?  Just wondering if it's actually retrying the request, and hence, the promise isn't actually rejected in the redis.async call.  It seems to be that the Redis get() call isn't rejecting the promise.

Comment: yes I need to restart the nodejs. the app is incapable to operate without the Redis in working condition.

Comment: think u r right, if I use get(key, () => ) it seems to be working as intended, the promise is not rejecting.

Comment: the solutions seems to be creating my own promises rather than depending on promisify